# Does "Il" refer to "on" in "On était gai. Il se versait des petits verres."

Tags: pronoms

The question is on the last two sentences of this passage from Flaubert's L'Éducation sentimentale.

> Des arbres la couronnaient parmi des maisons basses couvertes de toits à l’italienne. Elles avaient des jardins en pente que divisaient des murs neufs, des grilles de fer, des gazons, des serres chaudes, et des vases de géraniums, espacés régulièrement sur des terrasses où l’on pouvait s’accouder. Plus d’un, en apercevant ces coquettes résidences, si tranquilles, enviait d’en être le propriétaire, pour vivre là jusqu’à la fin de ses jours, avec un bon billard, une chaloupe, une femme ou quelque autre rêve. Le plaisir tout nouveau d’une excursion maritime facilitait les épanchements. Déjà les farceurs commençaient leurs plaisanteries. Beaucoup chantaient. **On était gai. Il se versait des petits verres.**

**Question**

1. Am I correct to think that *Il* refers to *on* in the sentence just before?
2. If yest to 1, is it an acceptable alternative to repeat *on* so that we get:

> On était gai. On se versait des petits verres.

3. If no to 1, what is *Il* then referring to?

**Background**

Please also see [this related post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19494/understanding-the-impersonal-pronoun-in-il-se-versait-des-petits-verres). In it, I assume the substance of qoba's answer below (i.e. saying no to 1 and saying that *Il* is an impersonal pronoun) and ask further questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. "Il" is an impersonal pronoun here, as in "Il pleut". This translates to English passive voice, as in "Small glasses were being poured".

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is *se* that turns the verb into the passive (or "middle") voice? Then is *des* not an indefinite article, but *de* + *les*?

Comment: The use of the impersonal pronoun has for main effect that the subject of the verb isn't specified. It roughly translates to English passive voice because that's how English speakers would typically make a sentence where the subject is implied, but it doesn't actually need to be used with "se". For example "il tombe de la neige" (snow was falling). However, aside from weather, I think the construction is mostly only used with reflexive verbs (il se fait tard, il se fait faim, il se trouve beaucoup de gens dans cette situation, il ne s'en trouve pas un pour rattraper l'autre, etc.).

Comment: As for "des", it is not the contraction of "de les" but the indefinite article, denoting the many glasses being poured, which are not specifically identified at this point in the sentence.

Comment: Here are some more examples from http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic34254-le-pronom-impersonnel.html -- Il manque deux euros.
Il se passe de drôles de choses.
Il reste trois parts.
Il règne une atmosphère étrange.
Il jaillit du pétrole.
Il court une rumeur.
Il flotte une bonne odeur.
Il pousse ici de nombreuses plantes.
Etc.
Il y a également, entre autres,  les pronominaux à sens passif.
Il se vend beaucoup de livres.

Comment: I've never seen an impersonnal "il" used this way... Imo, it should refere to someone, but can't know who in this quote...

Comment: Given context, it's obvious that it's not someone in particular who is pouring himself some shots, but rather people in general. I agree that it's uncommon and in this case literary.

Comment: Indeed, it would make sense to be impersonal, but I've never heard of "il" used as a "on"... Imo, the impersonnal "il" is used in sentences like "il fait beau" where "il" doesn't refer to anyone. Here, "il" would refer to "people", I think this is really different... But once again, I may be mistaken...

Comment: "it's not someone in particular who is pouring himself some shots, but rather people in general."--But you (qoba) don't mean that *Il* is a reference to people in general. According to your answer *Il* is a place holder and the real subject of the sentence is *des petits verres*. This seems even more obvious for *Il se vend beaucoup de livres*.  Here *many books are being sold*, and there is no reference to any person or people selling anything.

Comment: A rough analogue in English may be: *This model sells well* or *This road travels faster*. There is no reference to any person or people selling or traveling. (It's not the sentence but our knowledge of the world that tells us selling or traveling requires human beings.)